# Can't install elementtree with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, elementtree

Trying to install `elementtree` package with `pip`. Getting the following error:

```
    (taximachine_env)vagrant@dev-gm:/opt/taxi/taxiconsole$ pip install elementtree -vvv
Collecting elementtree
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/elementtree/
  1 location(s) to search for versions of elementtree:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/elementtree/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/elementtree/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/elementtree/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement elementtree (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for elementtree
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 294, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 250, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/opt/taxi/envs/taximachine_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 571, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for elementtree
```

PyPI [link](https://pypi.python.org/simple/elementtree/) returns the following response:

```
<head>
    <title>Links for elementtree</title>
    <meta name="api-version" value="2">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Links for elementtree</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any other way to install `elementtree`?

Comment: You already have it installed, it's in the stdlib : https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's in the stdlib: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. No need to install it with pip.

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET